# Element renders each time button is clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

For the sake of practice I am trying to render an element on submitting the form but each time I click the button element renders on the page but it should render only once in the case of an invalid value.

My question is how to execute function **renderError()** only once, when Submit button is clicked?

The code I'm trying to accomplish this with is:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.form')

const renderError = () => {
  const newElement = document.createElement('div')
  newElement.className = 'error'
  newElement.innerHTML = `
   <img class="error__icon" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="error icon" />
   <p class="error__message">Please provide a valid email</p>
  `
  const rootElement = document.getElementById('error__container')
  rootElement.append(newElement)
}

const validateForm = () => {
  const isValid = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/
  
if (isValid.test(email.value)) {
    // return something
  } else {
    renderError()
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  validateForm()
})
```

```html
<div class="form__container">
  <form class="form" novalidate>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" aria-label="Email" placeholder="Email Address" />
    <div id="error__container"></div>
    <button class="submit">
      <img src="images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="submit icon">
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code (HTML) so that we can replicate your issue.

Comment: Added. I know there are simpler ways of accomplishing this but I'm curious what I'm doing wrong in this case.

Comment: You've got some problems with your code even parsing correctly. Please edit the question and correct the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new error element each time. Try to find the one created before (by id, for example). Create it only if you need it. This is often called "lazy" initialization.

```js
// lazily return the error element (create it if we can't find it)
const errorElement = () => {
  let element = document.getElementById('errorElement')
  if (!element) {
    element = document.createElement('div')
    element.className = 'error'
    element.id = 'errorElement';
    const rootElement = document.getElementById('error__container')
    rootElement.append(element)
  }
  return element
}

let count = 0
const validateForm = () => {
  const isValid = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/
   
  if (isValid.test(email.value)) {
    // return something
  } else {
    const element = errorElement();
    element.innerHTML = `something went wrong ${++count} times`
  }
}


const form = document.getElementById('myform')
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  validateForm()
})
```

```html
<div class="form__container">
  <form id="myform" class="form" novalidate>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" aria-label="Email" placeholder="Email Address" />
    <div id="error__container"></div>
    <button class="submit">Button
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. It was obvious that I'm creating new element on each button press but puzzled me how to prevent it. Thank you.

Comment: In your opinion what is preferable way of showing an error message when dealing with forms. Should we include necessary HTML in html file and toggle its visibility or should we dynamically inject the html with JavaScript with innerHTML or insertAdjacentHtml?

Comment: My own preference would be to not manipulate the DOM directly at all. Use a framework that abstracts that job like angular or react or vue.  If you're just making a tiny app with no time for the monster framework, then I'd put an empty div (styled with a min-height that's taller than the text), and just change it's inner text.

Answer (score 0):

One solution: you can clear the contents of the `rootElement` before re-rendering:

```js
const renderError = () => {
  const newElement = document.createElement('div')
  newElement.className = 'error'
  newElement.innerHTML = `
   <img class="error__icon" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="error icon" />
   <p class="error__message">Please provide a valid email</p>
  `
  const rootElement = document.getElementById('error__container')
  rootElement.innerHTML = ""; // <-- Empty before appending
  rootElement.append(newElement)
}
```

Another solution would be to add the newElement in the HTML, hide it using `visibility: hidden` and then toggle a class on/off that will turn the visibility value to `visible` and `hidden`. This way, when the render error runs, it will just add a special class that will display the error element and upon clicking again the element will just get the class enabled again without re-appearing.

Comment: Thanks KostasX for your answer. Seems like the first approach you mentioned has some issues. Apparently error message stays visible even if value is valid.

Comment: You should add the relevant code in the if statement. This code will be responsible for disabling/hiding the message.